# Inequality proof: $x^a + y^b < x^b + y^a$ with $b > a$ and $x > y$ and $x,y > 1$ and $a,b \geq 1$ and $a,b \in \mathbb N$

Tags: inequality

Tried for a couple hours but couldn't come up with anything conclusive. Any ideas? I also couldnt find any counter examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given $b>a$, then

$x^{a}+y^{b}<x^{b}+y^{a}$ is the same as $x^{b}-x^{a}>y^{b}-y^{a}$ which is the same as

$$x^{a}(x^{b-a}-1)>y^{a}(y^{b-a}-1)$$

As $x>y$, and $a$ is a natural number and $x,y>1$, $x^{a} > y^{a}$ and also $x^{b-a}>y^{b-a}$ by the same argument as as $x,y>1$, $x^{b-a}$, $y^{b-a}>1$ so $y^{b-a}-1>0$, $x^{b-a}-1>0$, so if it is clear that if $e>f>0$ and $c>d>0$ implies $ec>fd$; hence we have our result.

Comment: Dang, I should've seen that. Thanks for the answer!